# "Will [somebody] be getting [something] in" vs "will [somebody] get [something] in"

Tags: sentence-choice, future-continuous

Why does a customer ask a shop assistant "will you be getting any more in" instead of "will you get any more in"?

Why is future continuous used and not future simple?

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is little difference in substantive meaning. However, use of the continuous implies repetition whereas the simple future is silent on that issue. Usually if a shop is going to stock an item, it will receive deliveries over time rather than as a singular event. Consequently, the continuous reflects the speaker’s recognition of normal practice.

Notice that the future continuous would not be used in the question below because now the focus is a singular event

> When will you next get some in?

Comment: In a hotel, why does a receptionist use future continuous in the question "how long will you be staying"? The reason of using continuous tense in this case is a bit different, right?

Comment: 'Staying in a hotel' is a continuous process, isn't it? It's natural to use the continuous tense when you don't know when the process will end.

Comment: +1.  As a corollary to receiving multiple deliveries over time rather than a singular event, a question that uses **will you be getting** wants to know if the new stock will arrive reasonably soon, not next season.